# hyper-v services won't start

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8.1

After revisiting hyper-v on my workstation after nearly a year suddenly it seems that the services aren't running and i can't seem to start them

steps i've taken:

- Checked that virtualization is still enabled in the BIOS
- tried DISM  (operation completed succesfully)
- rebooted several times throughout these steps
- tried removing hyper-v from windows features to reinstall (doesn't work: "can't 'install' features, rolling back changes" message)
- looked around on technet trying to find a solution
- vmms logs don't seem to show anything (as far as i can see)
- sfc /scannow: no problems found
- BCDEDIT /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

any ideas?

Comment: What's the error you get when trying to start services ?

Comment: @user2196728 Error 1068 The dependency service or group failed to start

Comment: Can you let us know your environment details?

Comment: I had a similar problem and, among the services, it looks like some HyperV-related ones are missing. I couldn't find a way to restore them back, though.